# How to reorder auto increment column values, after deleting any row other than last row?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, auto-increment

I want to know is there any **SQL query for asp.net,c#** that can just re arrange auto increment coloumn values..

eg.
deleting 2 in the table:

sno

1

2

3

4

does:

sno

1

3

4

but i want re-arrangement:

sno

1

2

3

Note:

1. Don't want to to the numbering manually
2. query to create table is like this:

`CREATE TABLE uid (sno int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, qpname nvarchar(500), mob int, tm int)`

Comment: copy all data to another table, truncate the initial table and again copy data from backup table to parent table.

Comment: DONT! Just leave them alone

Comment: You have to drop the `IDENTITY` column and recreate it, but I would strongly advise against this. You can always `SELECT` continuous row numbers using `ROW_NUMBER`. It is preferable for PKs to stay immutable.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos will dropping identity column not affect other column data? and do i do that?

Comment: Dropping the identity will normally not affect any other column data (you could of course have something like a filtered index using the field). However this may not be possible if the identity column is a foreign key in some other table.

Comment: @It'satrap this sounds good , but is there any way to create temporary backup table like can it be done through disconnected - model/adapter -table  in asp.net, not creating the backup table  actually in DB.?

help with the code will be appreciated..

Comment: There is no way you can achieve what i said without creating a table in DB.

Comment: There is high chance that you really don't need to do that, you just think that you do.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos How do i do that? i mean i can drop the column but will it be added in the same table as before ,starting with 1 and in order?

this sounds helpful as i don't have much values (around 30-50).

Help with the code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your table be named Parent and table that will hold the backup is called Backup. They should have identical columns.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Backup 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Parent
```

Now truncate the parent table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Parent
```

Now you can just insert the data back using the first command and just reversing the table names.

Remember that this may not work in all cases. You may have `On delete cascade` on and if that is the case, then you would loose all data from other tables also which are referencing the parent table. I think that you should never use this is you are using any Foriegn Key reference on this table.

Comment: It's a trap

 I have 2 questions here.

1.while inserting and copying all values into backup table, will auto increment values start from 1 and in order?


2.Will truncating a table and again inserting values, have same effect?(auto increment values start from 1 and in order?)


and thanks .. I will mark this ans once it works.

Comment: yes definitely. Another thing you may have to take care is you may have to write individual column names is the query instead of `*` and omit the Identity column

Answer (score 0):

Following are the queries which should run 1 after other to get this functionality done. This can be easily achieved in C# by executing a generic ExecuteNonQuery().

```
DELETE FROM TBL1 WHERE sno = @sno; 

UPDATE TBL1
SET sno = sno -1
WHERE sno > @sno;
```

Comment: you need to execute it in loop to get the functionality achieved for multiple rows to be deleted.