# Reset autoincrement of column after deleting one row

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the same problem as him

[How to reorder auto increment column values, after deleting any row other than last row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232822/how-to-reorder-auto-increment-column-values-after-deleting-any-row-other-than-l)

However, I cannot find a solution to my problem.

I need to update the the column as it will be shown to a dataGridView automatically.

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to do this?

Comment: The question you linked has an answer (aka a solution to your problem). If it does not work for you, you should elaborate. (If the problem is the "dbo": you can just remove it, MySQL does not know what that is). Another answer would be: just don't bother about gaps in the autoincrement primary key and keep them that way. "It looks nicer" is no (good) reason to do such an operation in the database.